# Using the Raspberry Pi to build consumer products

Tags: boot, screen

I'm trying to build a consumer device which has TFT screen and when powered on will display the different options. (Specific to the product), something like when we turn on a printer we see the options on-screen in few seconds.

Just wondering if this is achievable with a Pi 3. I see that it takes a bit of time to boot-up.

Comment: Welcome to RPi board. Can you give more detail about it? For example how do you switch between options via GPIO or keyboard ? Either way is can be posible

Comment: The  short answer is yes. You will need to experiment to see if boot times are within acceptable limits. No one can answer this without a lot more info.

Answer (score 2):

@Steve Robillard is right in that I cannot answer your question specifically without a lot more information, but here are some pointers that should help:

On a Pi 2, using a minimal version of Raspbian called Minibian I have a boot time of less than 10 seconds(although it feels even less than that). I achieved this in this way:

**In /boot/cmdline.txt**

- *change console to tty1*
- *loglevel=3*
- *logo.nologo*

I then created a splashscreen and from the moment the screen Pi boots, until the login prompt is issued I do not see any words because of my splashscreen. To do this:

- *Install fbi package using apt-get*
- *Get 1920x1080 image and put it in /etc/splash.png*
- *Create script to display spashscreen at boot(Search for RPI splashscreen and you will find a tutorial including this script)*

In regards to the GUI for options you could create one with Python and Tkinter for example which had buttons with different callbacks. This program could be set to run at boot, and the user auto-logged in.

To make the program look more professional instead of starting a Desktop Environment and then starting your program you could start it byitself using the command `startx pathtoprogram`. Note that if it is a python program you would use the command `startx /usr/bin/python /path/to/program.py`.

All these things can make the Pi more commercial looking.